# How to get Customer Address in formated way and print it - Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, customer, email, customer-address, magento2.3.4

[image]

How to get the Customer Address like above format and how to print it, If there is more than one customer address how to get the particular address of the customer.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **create Model**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**CustomerAddress.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerAddress as CustomerAddressResourceModel;

class CustomerAddress extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomerAddressResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

**CustomerAddress.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomerAddress extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customer_address_entity', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerAddress**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerAddress;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomerAddress as CustomerAddressModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerAddress as CustomerAddressResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomerAddressModel::class,
            CustomerAddressResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

> And get your customer multiple address

```
    protected $addressMapper;
    protected $CustomerAddress;

    public function __construct(
        ...........................................................
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
   \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerAddress\CollectionFactory $CustomerAddress,
        ...........................................................
    ) {
        ...........................................................
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
        $this->CustomerAddress = $CustomerAddress;    
        ...........................................................
    }

    public function getMultipleAddress()
    {
        $cust_id = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId();
        $data = $this->CustomerAddress->create();
        $data->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$cust_id);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

and call in your phtml file

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($block->getMultipleAddress()->getData());
exit();
```

> for print like default address please follow **magento root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/address.phtml**

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

you can go into **Store >> Configuration >> Customers >> Customer Configuration >> Address Templates >> HTML**.

It is formatted address template you can adjust like below:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br />
{{var country}}<br />
{{depend telephone}}T: <a href="tel:{{var telephone}}">{{var telephone}}</a>{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br />F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br />VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

[image]
You should save the original formatted address just in case.
After adjusting it, just clear cache config.

Hope this will help you.